# SQL query design with configurable variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a web app that has a large number of tables and variables that the user can select (or not select) at run time.  Something like this:

In the DB:

```
Table A
Table B
Table C
```

At run time the user can select any number of variables to return.  Something like this:

```
Result Display = A.field1, A.Field3, B.field19
```

There are up to 100+ total fields spread across 15+ tables that can be returned in a single result set.

We have a query that currently works by creating a temp table to select and aggregate the desired fields then selecting the desired variables from that table.  However, this query takes quite some time to execute (30 seconds).  I would like to try and find a more efficient way to return the desired results while still allowing the ability for the user to configure the variables to see.  I know this can be done as I have seen it done in other areas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a temporary table, use a view and recompile the view each time your run the query (or just use a subquery or CTE instead of a view).  SQL Server might be able to optimize the view based on the fields being selected.

The best reason to use a temporary table would be when intra-day updates are not needed.  Then you could create the "temporary" table at night and just select from that table.

The query optimization approach (whether through a view, CTE, or subquery) may not be sufficient.  This is a rather hard problem to solve in general.  Typically, though, there are probably themes of variables that come from particular subqueries.  If so, you can write a stored procedure to generate dynamic SQL that just has the requisite joins for the variables chosen for a given run.  Then use that SQL for fetching from the database.

And finally, perhaps there are other ways to optimize the query regardless of the fields being chosen.  If you think that might be the case, then simplify the query for human consumption and ask another question

Comment: We are using what is considered to be a soft view through code.  It performs the same function.  And the page still takes 30 seconds to refresh.

The temp table generation at night won't work because the associated tables are getting updated throughout the day and we can't wait until the night to refresh everything.

We are using the stored procedures and subqueries.  Still results in a response time of 30 seconds.

The big boys have found a way to do this as I can see how some of their products work.  Any ideas how they do it?